# Testing whether string starts with or end with another string

Tags: ruby, string

How should I check whether a string starts or ends with a given string? There doesn't seem to be any built-in methods available (or maybe it's just the IDE I'm using that isn't having it show up: RDE)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

There are built in methods:

```
"String".start_with? "S" # true
"String".end_with? "4" # false
```

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Must have missed it!

Comment: I think they need to give these functions more descriptive names. :)

Comment: Maybe different versions of ruby have different names for it.

Comment: God bless Matz and Ruby. Although, I think they should be named `starts_with?` and `ends_with?`.

Comment: @Josh Pinter start_with? is consistent with other functions like eql? and include? - I think of it as a question "Does the string start_with?" rather than a statement "The string starts_with"

Comment: Fair enough, but if you think of how you actually use it when writing code, it's exactly like your latter statement, i.e. `"The string".starts_with?`

Comment: @DavidC And for conditionals, you would never say something like "If does the string start with?", you'd say "If the string starts with?".

Answer (score 9):

```
string.start_with?("substring")
string.end_with?("substring")
```

Returns true or false

Source:

http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F

http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F